# Sorting Text array in batch

Tags: arrays, sorting, batch-file

I am trying to update a properties file using batch file. The key "comp.array" contains a value like "comp1,comp2,machine2,state1" (This is just a sample value, but its actually very long). I have following points that are needed to complete this batch file. the sorting part is where I am facing trouble. In the examples that are available on the web, the sort is made on either numeric array or a user specified input array in command line. How can we sort an array created internally?

- Get the value of the comp.array into a string (Done)
- Convert it to an array (Done)
- add new value at the end (Done)
- Sort it in ascending order (ToDo)
- Convert array to comma delimited string and assign it back to the key.(ToDo)

  ```
  @echo off
  SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

  SET PKEY=comp.array
  SET PVAL=myval
  SET FILE=app.properties

  FINDSTR /B %PKEY% %FILE% >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
       ECHO No matching Key %PKEY% in %FILE%. Exiting..
       EXIT 0
  )
  MOVE /Y "%FILE%" "%FILE%.tmp"
  FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "%FILE%.tmp" ^|FIND /N /I "%PKEY%"`) DO (
       SET LINE=%%A
  )
  SET VALUE=%LINE:~18%
  ECHO %VALUE%

  SET /A J=0
  SET VALARR[0]=""
  FOR %%i in (%VALUE%) do (
      SET VALARR[!J!]=%%i
      SET /A J+=1
  )
  SET VALARR[!J!]=%PVAL%

  for /l %%n in (0,1,!J!) do (
      echo !VALARR[%%n]!
  )

  :: PLACE TO ADD SORT LOGIC

  FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=]" %%S in ("%LINE%") DO SET LINE=%%S
  SET /A LINE=%LINE:~1,6%
  SET /A COUNT=1
  FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`FIND /V "" ^<"%FILE%.bak"`) DO (
      IF "!COUNT!" NEQ "%LINE%" (
          ECHO %%A>>"%FILE%"
      ) ELSE (
          ECHO %PKEY%=%PVAL%>>"%FILE%"
      )
      SET /A COUNT+=1
  )
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    set "var=one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve"
    set "out="

    :: separate the elements, sort and concatenate again
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        'cmd /q /c "for %%a in (%var%) do echo(%%a"^|sort'
    ) do set "out=!out!,%%a"

    :: there is an initial comma to delete
    set "out=%out:~1%"
    echo %out%
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the standard `sort` command for this. The code below sort the VALARR array in ascending order and convert the result into a comma delimited string:

```
(for /L %%n in (0,1,%J%) do echo !VALARR[%%n]!) | sort > sorted.txt
set "string="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (sorted.txt) do set "string=!string!,%%a"
rem Eliminate the first comma:
set "string=%string:~1%"
```